# JQuery: need to hide div if input file is empty

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to hide a div for aditional coments if the input file is empty.

I don't mind if it's done with Jquery or plain Javascript.

I've used JQuery, I know that it's been called correctly because my alert pops up, but my function does not hide the div with ID: #instrucciones-adicionales and all its contents.

**HTML**:

```
            <script>
                alert( "Animation complete." );
                $(function () {
                    $("input:file").change(function () {
                        var fileName = $(this).val();
                        if (filename != "") {
                            $("#instrucciones-adicionales").hide();
                        } //show the button
                    });
                });
            </script>


    <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
       <input type="hidden" name="csrfmiddlewaretoken" value="Ka5bun8eHCmm5pReR7M9JCOxP8YxVq1sBfi79yqnXFEFWEksDE8WSDfgiYxf2KDb">

    <div class="form-group">

       <div id="div_id_imagenes" class="form-group">

            <label for="id_imagenes" class="col-form-label  requiredField">
                Imagenes<span class="asteriskField">*</span>
            </label>


                <div class="">
                    <input type="file" name="imagenes" class="clearablefileinput" required id="id_imagenes">

                </div>


    </div>

      <div id="instrucciones-adicionales">

           <p class="bold-font"> Instrucciones adicionales (opcional):</p>


   <div id="div_id_instrucciones" class="form-group">
      <label for="id_instrucciones" class="col-form-label  requiredField">
                    Instrucciones<span class="asteriskField">*</span>
                </label>




       <div class="">
           <textarea name="instrucciones" cols="40" rows="10" class="textarea form-control" required id="id_instrucciones">
    </textarea>


    </div>


 </div>





  </div>
 </div>


 </br>
 </br>

 <p>O, sáltate este paso y envía tu arte por correo electrónico</p>


  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-naranja text-white btn-block">Continuar
                        </button>
```

Comment: What do you think this means? _filename != ""_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You had a typo (variables are case sensitive - `fileName` !== `filename`).
2. I added the `show` part:

```js
alert( "Animation complete." );
$(function () {
    $("input:file").change(function () {
        var fileName = $(this).val();
        if (fileName != "") {
            $("#instrucciones-adicionales").hide();
        } else {
            $("#instrucciones-adicionales").show();
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<main role="main">


    <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
       <input type="hidden" name="csrfmiddlewaretoken" value="Ka5bun8eHCmm5pReR7M9JCOxP8YxVq1sBfi79yqnXFEFWEksDE8WSDfgiYxf2KDb">

    <div class="form-group">

       <div id="div_id_imagenes" class="form-group">

            <label for="id_imagenes" class="col-form-label  requiredField">
                Imagenes<span class="asteriskField">*</span>
            </label>


                <div class="">
                    <input type="file" name="imagenes" class="clearablefileinput" required id="id_imagenes">

                </div>


    </div>

      <div id="instrucciones-adicionales" style="display: none">

           <p class="bold-font"> Instrucciones adicionales (opcional):</p>


   <div id="div_id_instrucciones" class="form-group">
      <label for="id_instrucciones" class="col-form-label  requiredField">
                    Instrucciones<span class="asteriskField">*</span>
                </label>




       <div class="">
           <textarea name="instrucciones" cols="40" rows="10" class="textarea form-control" required id="id_instrucciones">
    </textarea>


    </div>


 </div>





  </div>
 </div>


                        </br>
                        </br>

                        <p>O, sáltate este paso y envía tu arte por correo electrónico</p>


                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-naranja text-white btn-block">Continuar
                        </button>


                    </form>

</main>
```

Comment: ty, but still seeing the div when loading the page. I need it to be hidden at the begging and to show when file is uploaded.

Comment: Not your original question, but you can hide it using `style="display: none"`. Check the update on the answer.

Comment: That hides the div, but after uploading a file the div does not appear. I need it to hide and the beggining but to show when user uploads a file.

Comment: You are keep changing what you are looking all the time... it doesn't really work this way.

Comment: sorry for the confusion.  The title says: "need to hide div if input file is empty".  So the first action should be to show and then to hide in the if else condition. Div must have stile hidden for this to work. ty